# How to predict when a disk runs out of space?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I collect Free disk space metrics at regular intervals and would like to predict when the disk will be full.

I thought I could use [series_decompose_forecast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-decompose-forecastfunction)

Here's a sample query:

```
let DiskSpace = 
range Timestamp from ago(60d) to now() step 1d
| order by Timestamp desc
| serialize rn=row_number() + 10
| extend FreeSpace = case
(
    rn % 5 == 0, rn + 5
    , rn % 3 == 0, rn -4
    , rn % 7 == 0, rn +3
    , rn
)
| project Timestamp, FreeSpace;
DiskSpace
| make-series 
    FreeSpace = max(FreeSpace) default= long(null)
    on Timestamp from ago(60d) to now() step 12h
| extend FreeSpace = series_fill_backward(FreeSpace)
| extend series_decompose_forecast(FreeSpace, 24)
| render timechart
```

And the result

[image]

The baseline seems like it could show me when it will hit zero (or some other threshold), but if I specify more `Points`, it excludes more points from the learning process (still unsure if it excludes them from the start or end).

I don't even care for the whole time series, just the date of running out of free space. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [series_fit_line()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-fit-linefunction) is more than enough in this scenario.
Once you got the slope and the interception you can calculate any point on the line.

```
range Timestamp from now() to ago(60d) step -1d
| extend rn = row_number() + 10
| extend FreeSpace = rn + case(rn % 5 == 0, 5, rn % 3 == 0, -4, rn % 7 == 0, 3, 0)
| make-series FreeSpace = max(FreeSpace) default= long(null) on Timestamp from ago(60d) to now() step 12h
| extend FreeSpace = series_fill_forward(series_fill_backward(FreeSpace))
| extend (rsquare, slope, variance, rvariance, interception, line_fit) = series_fit_line(FreeSpace)
| project slope, interception, Timestamp, FreeSpace, line_fit
| extend x_intercept = todatetime(Timestamp[0]) - 12h*(1 + interception / slope)
| project-reorder x_intercept
| render timechart with (xcolumn=Timestamp, ycolumns=FreeSpace,line_fit)
```

| x_intercept |
| --- |
| 2022-12-06T01:56:54.0389796Z |

[image: Graph]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA21RzU7EIBC++xRzMQFtY+u6eurVF9CbMQ0L011cCnWgtiY+vHS7lmo8MfMNfD8DCbtHeNYt+iDaDhpyLVg3MA7Bgdg7dl8oDj5gB3mpLr4Ax4BWAVmogNxQ277dIcX711AWaf5IiE+dkDhds3EohUcWq0vYQlVBkcE2g1O/Off53Rl4OAObDAoeKVtxxNwjafS/eFsxsqXnoLARvQkVGGf3zPbGcHD2b7glU8w3Bz2FK28P/5ufdetGG1M3jgZBiq2xnZDHE5ic8MTEyL/3gjADb1wXjw9BWlgZK0qltgFJYhe0sxkYbTFyB75WD/UEr0SiRkfuDWX4of7NssTOUpzEnRyO9fIu6gWnRMAQ37KF4KV45ZBPG7piZfzJtQ7czOorOzmhI4W0Zo5TimIRnKjlQVCAQYcDsFE607e2Wtn9nCFfJd/LSr4ByFGP07ACAAA=)

P.S.

- No need for *serialize* after *order by*.
- No need for *order by* if you create the range backwards.
- Null value in a time-series breaks a lot of functionality (fixed with additional series_fill_forward)

Comment: These tips in the P.S. section are gold! Thank you. I'll try it out and compare

Comment: I have to learn a bit more about linear regression. So far, the `x_intercept` calculation is not clear to me. Especially if I'd like to know the intercept at 10% or 5%.

Comment: It is simply a linear equation, `y = ax + b`, where you are looking for y = 0, therefore `x = -b/a`.  The basic unit in our case is `12h`, so x0 is the 1st point in the timeseries minus 12 h. The y for x0 is the interception.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-decompose-forecastfunction
You will see that they add 0 slots into the "future" of the original series which the forecast then predicts.

This is also stated in the notes:

> The dynamic array of the original input series should include a number of points slots to be forecasted. The forecast is typically done by using make-series and specifying the end time in the range that includes the timeframe to forecast.

To make your example work:

```
let DiskSpace = 
range Timestamp from ago(60d) to now() step 1d
| order by Timestamp desc
| serialize rn=row_number() + 10
| extend FreeSpace = case
(
    rn % 5 == 0, rn + 5
    , rn % 3 == 0, rn -4
    , rn % 7 == 0, rn +3
    , rn
)
| project Timestamp, FreeSpace;
DiskSpace
// add 4 weeks of empty slots in the "future" - these slots will be forecast
| make-series FreeSpace = max(FreeSpace) default=long(null) on Timestamp from ago(60d) to now()+24h*7*4 step 12h
| extend FreeSpace = series_fill_backward(FreeSpace)
| extend forecast=series_decompose_forecast(FreeSpace, 7*4*2)
| render timechart
```

The documentation could be a bit clearer but I think what the `points` parameter does is simply to omit the last `N` points from training (since they are empty and you don't want to include them in your forecast model)

Output:

[image: ADX series forecast]

To get when you hit close to 0:

```
let DiskSpace = 
range Timestamp from ago(60d) to now() step 1d
| order by Timestamp desc
| serialize rn=row_number() + 10
| extend FreeSpace = case
(
    rn % 5 == 0, rn + 5
    , rn % 3 == 0, rn -4
    , rn % 7 == 0, rn +3
    , rn
)
| project Timestamp, FreeSpace;
DiskSpace
| make-series FreeSpace = max(FreeSpace) default=long(null) on Timestamp from ago(60d) to now()+24h*7*4 step 12h
| extend FreeSpace = series_fill_backward(FreeSpace)
| extend forecast=series_decompose_forecast(FreeSpace, 7*4*2)
| mv-apply with_itemindex=idx f=forecast to typeof(double) on (
    where f <= 0.5
    | summarize min(idx)
)
| project AlmostOutOfDiskSpace = Timestamp[min_idx], PredictedDiskSpaceAtThatPoint = forecast[min_idx]
```

| AlmostOutOfDiskSpace | PredictedDiskSpaceAtThatPoint |
| --- | --- |
| 5/12/2022 13:02:24 | 0.32277009977544 |

Comment: Thanks to your explanation of the `points`, I finally understand it. One follow-up for the series_decompose. When I don't assign it to a column, it's a dynamic object with several metrics (baseline, seasonality, trend, etc.). But when it's assigned to the column, is it the baseline?

Comment: @Zikato Yes, I noticed that as well (several metrics vs just baseline). I don't know what the reason behind that is.